# how to match [ ] in regexp in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I have tried like below but not working

```
set line "set_load 10 serdes[10]"

if {[regexp {.\ [ . \ ]} $line } {
   puts "Find [] in line "
} else {

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. 'It's not working' is not sufficient evidence. Please edit your question to describe exactly what is happening and what you want to happen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since brackets are Tcl's command substitution syntax, you can't put them in double quotes unescaped.

```
% set line "set_load 10 serdes[10]"
invalid command name "10"
```

You need to escape them or use braces which don't allow command substitition within:

```
% set line "set_load 10 serdes\[10]"
set_load 10 serdes[10]
% set line {set_load 10 serdes[10]}
set_load 10 serdes[10]
```

This output is from an interactive `tclsh` session.

See https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm for the complete documentation of Tcl's syntax (only 12 rules).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regexp to do that, you can use [`string first`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M8) for example:

```
set line {set_load 10 serdes[10]}

if {[string first {[} $line] > -1 && [string first {]} $line] > -1} {
   puts {Found [] in line}
}
```

Will print `Found [] in line`

If you insist on using regexp, then I guess you can use something like this:

```
set line {set_load 10 serdes[10]}

if {[regexp {\[.*\]} $line]} {
   puts {Found [] in line}
}
```

Note that in the first method, the order of `[` and `]` are being ignored, but can easily be asserted by getting the indices of the matches in the string. In the second method, the order of `[` and `]` have to be one after each other. Ignoring order is possible, but it will make the expression slightly more complex.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.*` instead of `.+` since the later will not accept `[]` (no characters between)

Comment: @osundblad Yea, you're right. Didn't think of it much at the time. Thanks!

Comment: Your solution with `string first` will match `abc ] def [ ghi`. Is this intended?

Comment: @DonalFellows Yes, that's why I have the last paragraph in my answer, due to OP did not specifying that aspect of the problem.